# TypeError: StreamListener.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'auth'

Tags: json, pandas, twitter, pymongo, tweepy

```
client = MongoClient(mongod_connect)
db = client.Data_Extractfrom_Twitter 
tweets = db.Tweets_Collections 
tweets.create_index([("id", pymongo.ASCENDING)],unique = True)

stream_auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
stream_auth.set_access_token(OAUTH_TOKEN, OATH_TOKEN_SECRET)

stream_api = tweepy.API(stream_auth)

track = ['Presidential Election with Donald Trump and Joe Biden']

class MyStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
    def on_status(self, status):
        print (status.id_str)
        try:
            tweets.insert_one(status._json)
        except:
            pass

    def on_error(self, status_code):
        if status_code == 420:
            #returning False in on_data disconnects the stream
            return False
myStreamListener = MyStreamListener()
myStream = tweepy.StreamListener(auth = stream_api, listener=myStreamListener)
myStream.filter(track=track)
```

I am using the current version of the jupyter and I am trying to **extract the data (i.e) tweets from Twitter to MongoDB.** For that I got all the access keys and tokens and made connection to MongoDB. **I used the tweepy 3.9.0 version StreamListener API for downloading the messages**, but I am getting this error please help me with this.

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [6], line 14
     12             return False
     13 myStreamListener = MyStreamListener()
---> 14 myStream = tweepy.StreamListener(auth = stream_api, listener=myStreamListener)
     15 myStream.filter(track=track)

TypeError: StreamListener.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'auth'
```